# Html.EditorFor retrieve null in decimals ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html-editor

I have a problem when retrieving a decimal data in my view. It occurs using Google Chrome and M.Edge, but with I.Explorer and Firefox is not happening.

This is my model:

```
public Nullable<decimal> TA_RATE_CARD_COST { get; set; }
```

This is the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TA_RATE_CARD_COST, "DecimalNullable")
```

When the value stored in the database is for example 500,54 the view does not retrieve the value, the EditorFor is empty.

[image]

If the value stored is 500 the data is retrieved correctly, like I show you.

[image]

Why is this happening? I remember with a old version of Chrome this works correctly. I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps Chrome does not recognize the decimal point. Have you tried to set the culture of your browser to US-EN?  You can do that easily in ASP.NET like this: protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    this.Culture = "en-US";
    this.UICulture = "en-US";
    base.InitializeCulture();
}

Comment: Some other ways to set the culture - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306162/how-to-set-current-culture-programmatically-in-an-asp.net-application

Comment: how is this value 500,54 assigned to decimal type